# How to Load Scala Class at Runtime, and try to get the ClassTag and create a generic class with this Type Info

Tags: scala, generics

Have a generic method as below:

```
def saveAvro[T](inputPath: String, outputPath: String, context: SQLContext, rowTag: String)(implicit et: ClassTag[T]) {
    ...
    Option(jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml._1.toString())).asInstanceOf[T] )
    ...
    nrdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(outputPath, className,
    classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable],
    classOf[AvroKeyOutputFormat[T]],
    job.getConfiguration)
     ...
   }
```

if works fine, but when we need another level generic and dynamic loading the class by give class full package path, like `com.xxx.xxx.classname`, we try to change to something like below, instead of given `ClassTag[T]`:

```
def saveAvro(fullclasspath: String, inputPath: String, outputPath: String, context: SQLContext, rowTag: String){

    val klazz = Class.forName(fullclasspath)
    //how to do asInstance[T] ???
    //How to get classOf[AvroKeyOutputFormat[T]] ???
 }
```